# Query from multiple select tags in a form

Tags: php, sql

I have three select tags in a form:

```
   <form name="filter_form" method="POST" action="display_data.php">
Select a country:
<select name="country">
    <option name="country" value="AL">All</option>
    <option name="country" value="AU">Austria</option>
    <option name="country" value="BE">Belgium</option>

</select>
Select Type:
<select name="ASS">
    <option name="ASS" value="all">All</option>
    <option name="ASS" value="think">Think Tanks</option>
    <option name="ASS" value="network">Networks</option>
    <option name="ASS" value="NGO">NGOs</option>
</select>
Select EU Attitude:
<select name="EU">
    <option name="EU" value="all">All</option>
    <option name="EU" value="PRO">PRO EU</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit Filter" />
</form>
```

I have made three of these functions for every select tag, but when I filter the results it takes into consideration only the last select tag:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['country']))
{
    switch($_POST['country'])
    {
    case 'BE' : $countryName = 'Belgium';
                break;
    case 'AU' : $countryName = 'Austria';
                break;
    case 'BU' : $countryName = 'Bulgaria';
                break;

    default : $countryName = '';
              break;
    }
    $where = '';
    if($countryName != '')
    {
        $where = "WHERE Country='".$countryName."'";
    }   
}

if(isset($_POST['ASS']))
{
    switch($_POST['ASS'])
    {
    case 'think' : $type = 'Think Tank';
                break;
    case 'network' : $type = 'Network';
                break;
    case 'NGO' : $type = 'NGO';
                break;
    default : $type = '';
              break;
    }
    $where = '';
    if($type != '')
    {
         if(!empty($type)){
        $where .= " AND Type='".$type."'";
    } else {
        $where = "WHERE Type='".$type."'";
    }   
    }   

}


if(isset($_POST['EU']))
{
    switch($_POST['EU'])
    {
    case 'PRO' : $eus = 'PRO EU';
                break;
    case 'REFORM' : $eus = 'Reform EU';
                break;
    case 'ANTI' : $eus = 'Eurosceptic';
                break;
    default : $eus = '';
              break;

    }
    $where = '';
    if($eus != '')
    {
        if((!empty($countryName)) || (!empty($type))){
        $where .= " AND Attitude='".$eus."'";
    } else {
        $where = "WHERE Attitude='".$eus."'";
        }
        }
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM think ".$where.""); 
}
?>
```

When clicking the submit button I want to query all selected options from the form, but this does not happen. It takes into consideration only the last option.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full code update, since I have the entire code now. I removed the name="" from each of the options in your selects. You don't need to name each option so long as the select tag has a name.

In the revised code you posted, you were also resetting the value of $where in each block - but we need to retain the value of $where as-is, and potentially add to it in each block. If the user selects all three options, we'll need to continually build up the $where variable. If it's reset in each block, then you will *always* get only the last option selected.

I also removed the case statements entirely by changing the value of the options in the selects to reflect what you wanted the final value to be. I just had to add an if statement to catch if they had selected "all". I made all of the "all" options uniform as well.

```
<form name="filter_form" method="POST" action="display_data.php">
Select a country:
<select name="country">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
</select>
Select Type:
<select name="ASS">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="Think Tank">Think Tanks</option>
    <option value="Network">Networks</option>
    <option value="NGO">NGOs</option>
</select>
Select EU Attitude:
<select name="EU">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="PRO EU">PRO EU</option>
    <option value="Reform EU">Reform EU</option>
    <option value="Eurosceptic">Eurosceptic</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit Filter" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['country'])){
    $countryName = $_POST['country'];
    if ($countryName == "all") {
        $countryName = '';
    }   
    if($countryName != ''){
        $where = "WHERE Country='".$countryName."'";
    }   
}

if(isset($_POST['ASS'])){
    $type = $_POST['ASS'];
    if ($type == "all") {
        $type = '';
    }
    if($type != ''){
         if((!empty($countryName)) && ($type != '')){
            $where .= " AND Type='".$type."'";
         } else if ($type != '') {
            $where = "WHERE Type='".$type."'";
        }   
    }   
}

if(isset($_POST['EU'])){
    $eus = $_POST['EU'];
    if ($eus == "all") {
        $eus = '';
    }
    if($eus != ''){
        if(((!empty($countryName)) || (!empty($type))) && ($eus != '')){
            $where .= " AND Attitude='".$eus."'";
        } else if ($eus != '') {
            $where = "WHERE Attitude='".$eus."'";
        }
    }
}

if ($where) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM think ".$where.""); 
} else {
    echo "No choices selected.";
}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still it takes only the last option. I updated my code in the question. Maybe they should all be inside the first function?

Comment: Sweetness. If you could accept my answer, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should only give the `<select>` name. option only need value. also you didn't give method to your `<form>` if i'm not mistaken the default is GET.

```
<form method='post'>
<select name="ASS">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="think">Think Tanks</option>
</select>
<select name="EU">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="PRO">PRO</option>
</select>
<select name="EU2">
    <option value="all">E</option>
    <option value="PRO">A</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And then all you need to do to get the selected value is this:

```
$selected_value_ASS = $_POST['ASS'];
```

Also you checked for "NGO" in the first selcted and there isn't any option with this value. You did it with the other `<select>` tags as well.

Comment: <form metho... missing a d there, FYI.